# Am I able to take any deductions against a foreign investment property?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

In 2021 I purchased a foreign investment property. The property is land, zoned for residential use, with the intent that a home is built on it once approvals go through.
Needless to say it has not generated any income.
I also spent money on flying out to inspect the property, property purchase taxes, architect fees and more.

Am I able to take *any* deductions against this investment in my situation, either for federal or state (California)? e.g. real estate taxes, depreciation, etc.

I do not own a business and both my wife and I are W-2 employees.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. You can only take deductions from income for income-generating property, you cannot take deductions for investments. Some expenses related to your investment may be added to basis, but you should talk to a licensed EA or CPA about the details.

Comment: Just to confirm - the cost basis isn't relevant for 2021 taxes, correct? It would only apply when I sell / generate income from the property.

Comment: @Dandan when you sell, cost basis is irrelevant to income (it is relevant for a depreciation deduction, but in this case it's land, so not depreciable)